# Inserting string of numbers in an array as new elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, insert

I am reading in numbers from a text file, I have a total of 6000 and they're all on **last line of my text file**. I have already figured out how to create a list of numbers out of this long string - i.e., converted this long string of numbers into a list of size 6000. However, surprisingly, my list size was actually 5988. There is a discrepancy and for some reason, some lines have multiple numbers on them, even after I split them. Hence, they look like this:

```
...
1.79336e-07 # this is arr[0]
1.28945e-07 # .. arr[1]
4.60924e-08
1.52726e-08 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307
-2.62628e-08
-3.19098e-08 # arr[5]
...
```

This rare line only happens a couple of times, hence the difference between the expected size of 6000 and 5988.

I want to split these lines into their individual numbers, and insert them in their correct position in the list.. so change the numbers to:

```
...
1.79336e-07 # this is arr[0]
1.28945e-07 # .. arr[1]
4.60924e-08
1.52726e-08 
-1.79769e+307 
-1.79769e+307 
-1.79769e+307 
-1.79769e+307 
-1.79769e+307
-2.62628e-08
-3.19098e-08 # arr[10]
...
```

What is the best way to split this line and insert them as new elements in the list, creating a larger list?

This is how I currently read in my file:

```
Ux = re.split('  +', list(data_file)[-1])
```

Comment: Do you want help with reading from file or with your list? Do you operate on a list or a string? Could you post some code to work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read from a file, you can create a regex that matches all your use cases and add all results to a list.

Example string input:

```
line = """ 
1.79336e-07 # this is arr[0]
1.28945e-07 # .. arr[1]
4.60924e-08
1.52726e-08 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307
-2.62628e-08
-3.19098e-08 # arr[5]
"""
```

Regex: `([-]?\d+.\d+e[-+]?\d+)+`, check  [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for a full explanation on how it works.

Then using:

```
import re
for match in re.findall('([-]?\d+.\d+e[-+]?\d+)+', line):
    print(match)
```

Will result in:

```
1.79336e-07
1.28945e-07
4.60924e-08
1.52726e-08
-1.79769e+307
-1.79769e+307
-1.79769e+307
-1.79769e+307
-1.79769e+307
-2.62628e-08
-3.19098e-08
```

I haven't added any linebreaks ('\n'), but those will be ignored by the regex. A full code reading from a file will look similar to:

```
data = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        for match in re.findall('([-+]?\d+.\d+e[-+]?\d+)+', line):
            data.append(match)
```

Comment: Thank you! I never actually used regex, just this to read the last line in my file:Ux = re.split('  +', list(data_file)[-1]). So, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if you post your code so we know what might be causing the problem.

If those odd lines have the numbers always separated by a space, this would work:

```py
for i, a in enumerate(arr):
    if " " in a:
        arr.remove(a)
        for j, b in enumerate(a.split()):
            arr.insert(i+j, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I first splitted on ' ' each element of the list and flattened the nested lists

```
listr = ['1.79336e-07', '1.52726e-08 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307 -1.79769e+307']
def flatten(li):
return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten(x)
            for x in li), [])
newList = []
for i in listr:
    newList.append(i.split(' '))
newList = flatten(newList)
print(newList)
```